# More convenient way for Spring data with jpa to store utf-8 strings in SQL Server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am developing a project with spring boot and SQL server. Almost all of my strings are persian and needs to be stored as utf-8. but for every string field I'm forced to use `@Nationalized` annotation on every string field to force jpa to create that column as `nvarchar`. Otherwise the string won't persist correctly. Is there a more convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Hibernate documentation this is possible:

> If your application and database use nationalization, you may instead
>   want to enable nationalized character data as the default.
>
> You can do this via the hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data
>   setting or by calling
>   MetadataBuilder#enableGlobalNationalizedCharacterDataSupport during
>   bootstrap.

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-nationalized

In Spring Boot application.properties you have to set:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data =true
```

Comment: I did this in application.properties: spring.jpa.hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data=true, But that does'n work. How should I enable this in spring boot project?

Comment: @NarimanEsmaielyFard You forgot the `properties` part in between, spring.jpa. **properties** .hibernate.use_nationalized_character_data